# add text to div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I'm just starting to learn and I'm trying to write simple code to add text to a div box using java script but it gives me error query selector not defined
html code:

```
    <h2>List of items</h2>
<input class="text" type="text" placeholder="write text"><br>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addItem()">
<div class="list"></div>
```

java script code:

```
function addItem(){
        let getText = querySelector("text").value;
        let newText = document.createElement("div");
        newText.innerHTML = document.appendChild("getText");
        document.querySelector("list").appendChild("newText");
    }
```

Comment: `querySelector` is a method of `document` object. It should be `document.querySelector("text")`.

Comment: What's more, the string passed should be a selector instead of a class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. `querySelector` is a method of `document` object. It should be `document.querySelector("selector")`.
2. `document.appendChild` expects a `Node` instance. You are passing a string.
3. You are missing `.` for the class selectors.
4. You should not wrap variables with `""` when you are referring to them.

Here is the updated code:

```
function addItem() {
   let getText = document.querySelector("input.text").value;
   let newText = document.createElement("div");
   newText.innerHTML = getText;
   document.querySelector(".list").appendChild(newText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
document.querySelector("div.list").appendChild("newText");
```

instead of

```
document.querySelector("list").appendChild("newText");
```